# Images in WPF 4.0 are of lesser quality than in 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I just updated my app to .Net 4.0 from 3.5sp1

Which included removing references to the toolkit and exhange them with system.xaml.

Some more reference changing was required by me but I dont quite recall what they were.

Anyway, after I compiled and run it the the first thing that popped into my eyes is that all the images seem worse.

Here's a screenshot that show some of the changes, WPF 4.0 is on the right

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?96967dfde8.jpg]

Will appreciate any help.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 4):

Try setting [RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to Fant or HighQuality.  It looks like the default was changed in WPF 4.0.  From [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpf3d/whats-new-in-graphics-for-4-0-beta-1):

> The default
> RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode
> (Unspecified) is now Linear instead of
> Fant. If you still want Fant, you can
> re-enable it.